# How to access dependency injection container globally

Tags: php

I'm building my own small MVC framework in PHP, just to learn and get a better understanding.

I've create a small framework with Router.

In my index.php i've created a container for my application.

index.php

```
use \Oak\Route\Route as Route;
use \Oak\Route\Routes as Routes;
use \Oak\App\App as App;

$routes = new Routes();

$routes->addRoute(new Route('home', 'index', 'index'));
$routes->addRoute(new Route('user/{username}/{id}', 'index', 'about'));
$routes->addRoute(new Route('help', 'help', 'index'));

$container = new Container();
$container->set('app', function() use ($routes) {
    return new App($routes, new \Oak\Header\Request());
});

$app = $container->get('app');
$app->run();
```

---

Container.php & ContainerInterface.php

```
interface ContainerInterface {

public function set($name, $service);
public function get($name, array $params = array());
public function has($name);
public function remove($name);
public function clear();
}

class Container implements ContainerInterface {

    protected $services = array();

    public function set($name, $service) {
        if(!is_object($service)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Only objects can be registred");
        }

        if(!in_array($service, $this->services, true)) {
            $this->services[$name] = $service;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function get($name, array $params = array()) {
        if(!isset($this->services[$name])) {
            throw new RuntimeException($name ." has not been registred in the container");
        }
        $service = $this->services[$name];

        return !$service instanceof Closure ? $service : call_user_func_array($service, $params);
    }

    public function has($name):bool {
        return isset($this->services[$name]);
    }

    public function remove($name) {
        if(isset($this->services[$name])) {
            unset($this->services[$name]);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function clear() {
        $this->services = array();
    }

    public  function getServices():array {
        return $this->services;
    }
}
```

My questions is now how do i enable access to the container from my Controllers, my App-file etc. One solution would be to use Singleton or static methods in the container?

I've read a lot af blogposts and articles on the subject, but i seems that all examples only communicates with the container from the index file?

I was also starting experimenting with inheritance, that app extends the container, then pass it to the controllers?

My questions is, how do you enable access to the container from everywhere in your app, if that's the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the Singleton design pattern.. you need something like that :

```
class Container {
    private static $instance;
    //prevent from creating a container class by itself
    private function __construct() {};    
    /* .... */
    public static function getInstance() {
        if (self::$instance === null) {
            self::$instance = new Container();
        }
    }
}
```

Then everywhere in code instead of using `$container = new Container();` use `$container = Container::getInstance();`

Anyway I highly recommend you to checkout a Pimple (http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/) it's very nice code, with lazy loading. It will take you a lot of time to write something as good and feature rich as Pimple.